# H-PoPG Haplotyper NullPointerException Error at algorithms.HBOP2Builder

Tags: bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

Hello I am building a genome assembly method and a critical step of my pipeline is phasing. I've been searching through different methods and recently discovered H-PoPG which looks promising for polyploid haplotyping. I am trying to test my data on it but I got the following result and couldn't find any help or forum on the web.

This is the command I am using:

```
java -jar H-PoPG.jar -p 3 -w  0.9 -f fragment_matrix_Chrm1 -vcf PilonChrm1.vcf -o output_phased_Chrm1
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at algorithms.HBOP2Builder.<init>(HBOP2Builder.java:59)
at algorithms.HBOP2Builder.<init>(HBOP2Builder.java:25)
at algorithms.HPBOP2Alg.buildHaplotype(HPBOP2Alg.java:24)
at main.PolyPlotyping.Polyphasing(PolyPlotyping.java:224)
at main.PolyPlotyping.go(PolyPlotyping.java:159)
at main.PolyPlotyping.main(PolyPlotyping.java:280)
srun: error: neumann: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction by explaining me where this error could come from?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have run your data and found it is OK to run the command  without the vcf file.
The error messages occur when it is run with the vcf file.
The vcf file contains many overlaps such as:

```
Chromosome_1_Reference  16      .       A       .       1486    LowCov  DP=39;TD=43;BQ=38;MQ=57;QD=38;BC=39,0,0,0;QP=100,0,0,0;PC=119;IC=0;DC=0;XC=0;AC=0;AF=0.00       GT      0/0
Chromosome_1_Reference  16      .       AAACCC  A       .       Amb;LowCov      DP=56;TD=60;BQ=39;MQ=57;QD=25;BC=19,21,0,0;QP=48,52,0,0;PC=119;IC=0;DC=16;XC=1;AC=1;AF=0.29     GT      0/1
Chromosome_1_Reference  17      .       A       C       1018    Amb;LowCov      DP=56;TD=60;BQ=39;MQ=57;QD=25;BC=19,21,0,0;QP=48,52,0,0;PC=119;IC=0;DC=16;XC=1;AC=1;AF=0.52     GT      0/1
```

Please check the vcf file and ensure that every SNP position is covered by only one line, 
and that the last column of each line should be 0/0/1 or 0/1/1 when the polyploidy is 3 (-p 3).

Comment: Hi! Are you saying there is an overlap because both line 1 and 2 have the value 16 on the 2 column? 

And for the last column, mine is different from yours, as it has more numbers following the ploidy (tetraploid) combination:
   0/0/0/1:17:10:379:7:231